# Failed to load the "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/subtotal" component. error on checkout/cart page after upgrading magento

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.5

[image]After upgrading Magento 2.2.3 to 2.3.5, I faced the list of these errors on my checkout cart page. Order summary details are also missing. I disable all the custom modules and extensions. Can any help me with this problem?